# Android - Apache commons libraries & Exchange Web Service Managed API

Tags: java, android, exchangewebservices, apache-commons-httpclient, ewsjavaapi

I am already trying the exchange web service in Java. It's running good. It has send email or get emails correctly.

My java code looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        WebCredentials webCredentials = new WebCredentials("asdasd@asasd.onmicrosoft.com", "asdasdasd");
        URI url = new URI("https://asdasd802.outlook.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
        service.setCredentials(webCredentials);
        service.setUrl(url);

        System.out.println(service.getRequestedServerVersion());

        msg.setSubject("Hello world!"); 
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("asdasd@gmail.com");
        msg.send();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }

}
```

When I try this in android with this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                WebCredentials webCredentials = new WebCredentials(
                        "asdasd@asdasd.onmicrosoft.com",
                        "asdasd");
                URI url = new URI("https://asdasd.outlook.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
                service.setCredentials(webCredentials);
                service.setUrl(url);

                EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
                msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
                msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText
                           ("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
                msg.getToRecipients().add("asdasd@gmail.com");
                msg.send();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I get some errors, when clicking on button.

This is the messages from the console :

```
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2011-12-15 17:06:25 - MobileApplication1] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Toggle HighlightingOpen in New WindowSelect All
```

This is the errors from log chat:

```
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): java.lang.VerifyError: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EwsServiceXmlWriter
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.emit(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.createItem(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.internalCreate(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.internalSend(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.send(Unknown Source)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.MobileApplication1.android.MainScreenActivity$1.onClick(MainScreenActivity.java:60)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-21 09:10:17.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Toggle HighlightingOpen in New WindowSelect All
```

I already add these libraries.

The Exchange Web Services (EWS) Java Managed API consists of a single package, microsoft.exchange.webservices.data and requires the following 3rd party libraries

- Apache Commons HttpClient (commons-httpclien.jar)
- Apache Commons Codec (commons-codec.jar)
- Apache Commons Logging (commons-codec.jar)
- JCIFS (jcifs.jar)
- EWS Java api.

What is the problem?

I have done some research. 
I see some where Android already have logging and httpclient in sdk libraries.

Comment: May this post is interesting for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203073/problems-using-the-ews-java-api-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Ansdroid already contains commons-http (not sure which version is used, but it is 4 or better), so you have to ensure that your build process does not pack  aleready contained jars into apk.

Another issue is class format complaint of DX - as it says, it is outdated and has to be recompiled. Also, check your dependency versions, and use recent ones 
( if you would use maven / ivy it would be easier )

Comment: There is no higher version of these libraries.

Apache Commons HttpClient (commons-httpclien.jar) 3.1
Apache Commons Logging (commons-codec.jar) 1.1.1

Comment: There are: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec   You may also grab sources for dsiered versions, and recompile them with modern compiler.